# pandas.Series.str.contains couldn't detect "[a-zA-Z]"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have been trying to remove the rows that contain alphabet characters as this one.

[rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9E5Zr.png)

And what I tried is

```
df = df[~df['tag_name'].str.contains("[a-zA-Z]")]
```

I did remove some rows in this way but some rows remained like this. And I found these characters look different from those I type in.

[characters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kDWc.png)

```
归创通桥-ＢB
```

Could it be something wrong with the encoding method? And does anyone know how I can remove these rows?

Comment: If im understanding correctly you are asking why there is a "B"- looking character not being removed? That is most likely because it is not actually a B, but a completely different character that just looks like B, nothing to do with encoding - e.g. Ｂ (http://www.unicode.org/Public/security/latest/confusables.txt)

Comment: @FlyingThunder  I'm trying to remove all the rows that have these weird characters. So they just look like they're from the alphabet but actually something else?

Comment: hard to say just from screenshots - you could just paste the actual rows in your question, but yes it looks like its not an actual B.

Comment: @FlyingThunder  I pasted it. They still look weirdly different.

Comment: ```"Ｂ"=="B"

False```

well, there you have it - its not the same character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you could try [`unicodedata.normalize`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize):

```
import unicodedata
df = df[~df['tag_name'].apply(lambda x: unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', x)).str.contains("[a-zA-Z]")]
```

Comment: Holy moly it worked! Thx a lot! So what the unicodedata.normalize() did is to transform these to alphabet characters, right?

Comment: @Sheng Yeap! transform these badly encoded characters to regular alphabet characters, feel free to mark my answer by clicking the check mark ✔️ if you like

Answer (score 1):

If you use `print(u"B".encode('ascii','backslashreplace'))`

you will see that the character is not actually a "B", but a FULLWIDTH LATIN CAPITAL LETTER B https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ff22/index.htm

Which is why your regex cant detect it

Comment: I see! And I managed to remove them via the method proposed by @U12-Forward . I still appreciate ur explanations tho, thank u!